# HotProperty advanced search error on php 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i had to migrate an old mambo site (which is based on joomla) to a new server wich has PHP 5.3.
After fixing all the mambo problems, the last problem is an hotproperty advanced search error.
Here is the error:

```
Unknown column \'p.type\' in \'on clause\' SQL=INSERT INTO mos_hp_temp (`id`, `price`) \n SELECT p.id, p.price\n FROM mos_hp_properties AS p, mos_hp_companies AS c\n LEFT JOIN mos_hp_prop_types AS t ON p.type = t.id\n LEFT JOIN mos_hp_agents AS a ON p.agent = a.id\n WHERE p.published=\'1\' AND p.approved=\'1\' AND t.published=\'1\'\n AND a.company=c.id\n    AND (publish_up = \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\' OR publish_up <= NOW())\n AND (publish_down = \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\' OR publish_down >= NOW())
```

I formatted it a little for a better readability.

```
Unknown COLUMN 'p.type' IN 'on clause' sql= 

INSERT INTO mos_hp_temp 
            ( ` id ` , 
             ` price ` ) 
SELECT p.id, 
       p.price 
FROM   mos_hp_properties AS p, 
       mos_hp_companies AS c 
       LEFT JOIN mos_hp_prop_types AS t 
              ON p.type = t.id 
       LEFT JOIN mos_hp_agents AS a 
              ON p.agent = a.id 
WHERE  p.published = '1' 
       AND p.approved = '1' 
       AND t.published = '1' 
       AND a.company = c.id 
       AND ( publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
              OR publish_up <= Now() ) 
       AND ( publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
              OR publish_down >= Now() )
```

I can't update anything for now, so it is not an option.
How can i solve this?
Naturally, i checked and mos_hp_properties has the type column.

Roby

Comment: Did you check the column "type" exists in the "mos_hp_properties" table ? Looks like to me the error message is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: if i do "select type from mos_hp_properties", the query succeeds. (The table has this column)

Comment: Do ***not*** mix implicit joins and explicit joins.

Comment: It's Mambo, not a script i made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The lines

```
mos_hp_properties AS p,
mos_hp_companies AS c
```

should be in reverse order.
Open components/com_hotproperty/hotproperty.php and change lines 711/712 with this code:

```
$sql2 .= "\n FROM #__hp_companies AS c, #__hp_properties AS p "
. "\n LEFT JOIN #__hp_prop_types AS t ON p.type = t.id"
```

Roby